# how to separate and sum 2 columns based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a select statement and I have a column I would like to separate into 2 columns based on their type, and then get the sum of the amounts grouped by an ID

[image: table1]

I want all the gold and platinum types in one column, and all the silver and bronze in a 2nd column, then summed and grouped by the ID so it looks like this :

[image]

I tried doing a union like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    SUM(Amount) AS "Gold/Platinum",
    0 AS "Bronze/Silver"
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    Type IN ('gold', 'platinum')
GROUP BY 
    ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ID, 
    SUM(Amount) AS "Bronze/Silver",
    0 AS "Gold/Platinum"
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    Type IN ('bronze', 'silver')
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

The gold/platinum column will be correct, but I get nothing in the bronze/silver column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when Type in ('gold', 'platinum') then amount else 0 end) as gold_platinum,
       sum(case when Type in ('bronze', 'silver') then amount else 0 end) as bronze_silver
from t
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Heh beat me to it by a few seconds. :D

Comment: That did the trick! I figured I'd have to do a case but I couldn't wrap my head around the logic. This makes a lot of sense thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this in SSMS:

```
   DECLARE @data TABLE( [ID] INT, [Type] VARCHAR(10), [Amount] INT );

    INSERT INTO @data ( [ID], [Type], [Amount] ) VALUES
    ( 1, 'gold', 100 )
    , ( 1, 'gold', 50 )
    , ( 1, 'bronze', 75 )
    , ( 2, 'silver', 10 )
    , ( 2, 'bronze', 20 )
    , ( 3, 'gold', 35 )
    , ( 4, 'silver', 20 )
    , ( 4, 'platinum', 30 );

    SELECT
        [ID]
        , SUM( CASE WHEN [Type] IN ( 'gold', 'platinum' ) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS [Gold/Platinum]
        , SUM( CASE WHEN [Type] IN ( 'bronze', 'silver' ) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS [Bronze/Silver]
    FROM @data
    GROUP BY [ID]
    ORDER BY [ID];
```

Returns

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | Gold/Platinum | Bronze/Silver |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |           150 |            75 |
|  2 |             0 |            30 |
|  3 |            35 |             0 |
|  4 |            30 |            20 |
+----+---------------+---------------+
```